# Play Framework 2.4.Trying to Alter main template based User Logged in status

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

First thank you for reading this far.Here is a basic introduction.
I have implemented the simple authentication demo in the play 2.4 documentation.
And Here is a method where i use it.

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public Result reviewSubmit(){
    //Review newReview = contactFormData.get();
    //newReview.save();
    Form<Review> reviewFormData = reviewForm.bindFromRequest();
    User user = User.findByEmail(request().username());

    if(reviewFormData.hasErrors()) {
          return badRequest("Form Field has Errors" +reviewFormData);
        }
    Review newReview =reviewFormData.get();
    newReview.user = user.fName +" " + user.lName;
    newReview.save();
    return redirect(routes.Reviews.review());

}
```

AS you can see as part of the review saving process i use

```
User user = User.findByEmail(request().username());
```

The request().username() gets the currently logged in users email address 
from which i use to find the user and access there first and last names when i go to save the review object later on.

What i want to know is there a way in which i can use

```
if(request.username() == null ){
    //Show login Button
}else{
    //show Logout button
}
```

Inside say a main.scala.html template as an easy way of altering the main template without passing a user object from every action.

Thanks for any help or pointers provided.
N.B as i am new to play and have really struggled to understand securescoial plugins/deadbolt/play-authenticate i just want a way of obfuscating the links shown

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am answering your question but why can't you do something like this

```
@if(user) {
  <button>LogOut</button>
} else {
   //login button
}
```

in your template.

Where user is passed into the template , as given in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates).

Comment: But then id have to pass the user information from every action throughout the app no?

Comment: My bad i had each of my controllers extending controller instead of the original application controller and was making this suggestion an ordeal.Thanks for your help.